# Editing Visio Shape Excel OLE Links

Tags: hyperlink, visio, ole

I have a Visio doc that has ~200 links to a collection of Excel spreadsheets. I have the spreadsheets but the Visio links point to a path that is inaccessible. I would like to change these. Using Visio Plan 2.

By a lot of experimenting the only way I could find was to open the doc, tell Visio to update the links, then when it failed go through the links in the convert dialog that appeared.

This dialog isn't very helpful as the file path is all jammed into a small text box with no resizing controls. Fortunately, I could see the end of the filename and that was sufficient for me to determine which file was for each link.

I had to edit each one of these entries individually as one can't group select and edit in this dialog.

Pain that it was, I did get the links hardcoded to another location, so at least that aspect works.

However, I need to have these as a relative location so that the vsd and xls files can travel together and any other user can open the vsd no matter the location, just so the vsd and xls are in the same folder.

I can't find a way to do this. I tried prepending the file name with '..\filename', Visio complained but I went through and edited all of them, saved, but it failed to find them when I re-opened the document.

How can I make a relative path in these? Is there an easier way to edit the links?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you are using OLE links ("insert OLE object, as a link"), not "Add Hyperlink"? Why not switch to the latter one? It supports relative links. Or do you mean that your Excel spreadsheets are EMBEDDED into Visio file?

Comment: I've inherited a Visio sheet that has embedded links in it to sections from several Excel files. I cannot find any way to edit the existing links, short of not having the excel files where it wants them and then telling it to let me manually adjust the links when the Visio file open fails, due to not finding the Excel files.

How those links were constructed when the Viso sheet was created is unknown to me.

with the crude editing I can do by using the file open fail thing, all I can do is point to a different absolute location, and I have to do it for every single link (200 of them).

Comment: Yes you explained that in the above text. I'm asking what kind of links are they? There are two type of links in Visio: OLE links (embed) and "Hyperlinks". Do your links look like this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-a-hyperlink-in-a-visio-drawing-271fb2a8-4081-47db-a333-487315c05085. I suspect the answer is "no". Then you could just use hyperlinks.

Comment: I get nothing in the ctl-k dialog so I suspect they are indeed OLE. I am looking for a way to edit these 'links'.

Comment: I am not quite sure - without seeing what you see it's hard to tell :) You could try asking here on a dedicated Visio forum: http://visguy.com/vgforum/

Comment: Oh, thx. I had forgotten about that forum.

Answer (score 0):

Call "Links" window via pane "Tell me what you want to do"
[image: "Links" window]